# how to update list after deleting an item?

Tags: android, database, list, sqlite, listview

I want to delete an item from arrayList and update it after delete. The query is performing delete operation but the list is not getting updated.
Below is the onItemLongClickListener code.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            help.deleteEntry(position);
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Delete..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Delete code of DatabaseHelper.

```
 public void deleteEntry(long id) {

    // delete row in user table based on id

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,KEY_ID + " = " + id,null);

}
```

Comment: After delete again  call `setAdapter()` method

Comment: after you delete data from db rebuild your listview by calling data fetching method again

Comment: show your remove() method..

Comment: how are you removing item from list???

Edited: try to pass only the position in remove() method

Comment: replace adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position)); with yourarraylist.remove(position)

Comment: call arrayList.remove(position); instead of adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position)) it will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write a method in adapter to remove the item:

```
public removeItem(int position){
  yourArrayList.remove(position);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call this method from onItemLongClick Of listview:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            adapter.removeItem(position);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice two things here first don't pass position to delete row from the database as the id is auto increment and secondly for delete you should `getWriteableDatabase()`

So your code should be like this

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Obj obj = adapter.getItem();
            help.deleteEntry(obj.getId());
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Delete..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In your `deleteEntry()` use this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
```